# Simple Rate Limiting Logic

Tags: java, api-design

I have a requirement where I need to add some rate-limiting functionality to an existing web application. The application reads transactions from a queue (`TXN` queue) and processes them in realtime. Each transaction has a unique id, a group id (a certain number of transactions belong to a particular group id), and the transaction status. The status can be either `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE`.

**Requirement**

Whenever a particular group id has a failed transaction (read from the `TXN` queue), at least one of the failures has to be posted to the fallback queue (`FALLBACK` queue).

**Example:**

Total Number of transactions read from `TXN` queue: 100 (5 Unique group id's having 20 transactions each).

Suppose if `GRP_ID1` has 5 failed transactions out of 20 transactions, then at least 1 failed transaction has to be sent to the `FALLBACK` queue. The remaining 4 failures can be ignored and the other 15 `SUCCESS` transactions will be processed by the web application.

Similarly, if all 20 transactions of a group id have failed, at least 1 `FAILURE` transaction has to be sent to `FALLBACK` queue. Not all 20 transactions should be posted to the `FALLBACK` queue. But a limit of say `10%` is acceptable ie. 10% of 20 = At most 2 transactions can be posted to the `FALLBACK` queue on `FAILURE`.

If there are no failures for a particular group ID, no action has to be taken and all the transactions will be processed by the web application.

**Points to note:**

- Transactions are not sequential either by unique id or group id. They can come in any order.
- At least one failure has to be reported for a particular group id.
- The web application runs on multiple threads on multiple hosts in realtime and will continuously poll the queue. It will not abort unless manually killed.
- We cannot persist the group id for lookup as it is space-consuming.
- A single group id can contain a million transactions too and all of them could also be failures or successes.

My solution was to add a simple odd/even logic such that all failed transactions having odd unique id would be pushed to the queue.

I can't think of anything else other than this. Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear.  You mention throttling in the title of the question but don't really talk about any specifics around that.  Things like "volume shouldn't be very high" don't really translate well into software implementations.  I'm not sure whether you should post all the transactions or stop/slow them when you hit some threshold of errors.  The first step to building a solid solution is getting a clear understanding of what you need to do.  If you can't explain it, you are unlikely to be able to code it.

Comment: @JimmyJames I've edited the question to make it more precise. Please go through and let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: So you can't even keep the group-id around in a table of "recently seen group-ids" (because it is too big)?  Then ... you're going to have difficulties.  I'll be interested to see what the solution is subject to this constraint.

Comment: @davidbak You could potentially use the fallback queue for this.  I'm hesitant to suggest this, though.  Messaging can be a real rabbit hole.  If I'm using messaging platforms, I'm using them for messaging, not as some sort of pseudo-db.

Comment: When you say you cannot persist the group id, what about temporary storage e.g. local memory or something like redis?  You'd need to have a way to resume after a restart, I presume, but that's a solvable problem.

Comment: w.r.t. OP's suggestion of pushing the odd group-id failures:  yes, and what if due to some unlikely hardware or software flaw all the failures had even unique-id?  you're going to need _some_ kind of storage if you're not going to route _all_ failures to the fallback queue yet still _guarantee_ to not miss any group_id (if I'm understanding the problem correctly).

Comment: The reason we do not want to store the group-id is because the processing volume is very high and the storage could easily build up. I also thought of a timed hashmap present in Gauva , but that brings in more complexity since we need to set the right expiration time (too small and the removal of expired entries will take up time and, too long and the build up would become huge).